# SQL INNER JOIN ON table1.column1 = table2.column2 OR ON ..?

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

What the SQL script if you want select database by INNER JOIN but with 2 ON and OR between ON.

This is my wrong script

```
SELECT * 
FROM user
INNER JOIN friend ON friend.id1_friend = user.id_user 
                  OR ON friend.id2_friend = user.id_user
WHERE id_user != '$_SESSION[user]' 
  AND friend_status != '2'
ORDER BY id_user DESC
```

Comment: get rid of the second `ON`.

Comment: What was your justification for using 2 ONs? (Rhetorical.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on is use one time with one table. you just put or with other condition.

```
 SELECT*FROM user
INNER JOIN friend ON 
(friend.id1_friend=user.id_user OR friend.id2_friend=user.id_user)
WHERE id_user != $_SESSION[user]
AND friend_status != '2'
ORDER BY id_user DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * -- this is not smart
  FROM user u
  JOIN friend f
    ON u.id_user IN(f.id1_friend,f.id2_friend)
 WHERE u.id_user != '$_SESSION[user]' -- this is not safe
   AND f.friend_status != 2
 ORDER 
    BY u.id_user DESC
```